# Having Syntax Error in code java

Tags: java, netbeans

**Why is there a syntax error in this code?**

```
 String strSqlUpdate = "UPDATE Customers SET Contact = " + contact_num + "," 
          + "Email = '" + email_add + "'," 
          + "Address = '" + mail_add + "'," 
          + "SurveyStatus = " + radio_group + ","
          + "Subscription = " + receive_info + 
          "WHERE membership_ID = '" + member_ID';
```

I thought my code was right.

Comment: Do you have all of those variables declared and initialized?

Comment: When you compile what is the complete error message ?

Comment: Are we really talking about the Java syntax? Or the SQL syntax? Because e.g. before your "WHERE" is a probably space missing (if it's not included in receive_info).

Comment: @peeskillet yes,all are declared, for my INSERT statement, it is working well

Comment: @JoachimRohde SQL syntax written in netbean

Comment: @userNoldea, as Joachim Rohde explained, you need a space before the WHERE

Comment: do you mean + receive_info + " " + "WHERE MembershipID =" + member_ID;?
@peeskillet

Comment: @PeterMmm INFO:   SQL Exception hit: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(Contact)2222,Emailme@example.com,Address,hellotesting123456,SurveyStatus,0,Subs' at line 1

Comment: Yes, you can do that. Also, to note, you have many unnecessary `""`s. You can add the commas in like this `", SurveyStatus ,"`, instead of this `"," + "SurveyStatus" + ","`

Comment: You are also opening your system for SQL injection attacks by using String concatenating when creating SQL statements. One should never do it that way!.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is the error in your code, check all the variables that you have used are declared and initialized with proper values.

If it is the syntax of the sql that is bothering you , here is what your sql would look like if all the variables are initialized to null.

```
 UPDATE Customers SET (Contact)null,Emailnull,Address,null,SurveyStatus,null,SubscriptionnullWHERE MembershipID =null
```

Use spaces in your **strSqlUpdate** to correct the above sql.

**EDIT**

What you need is something like this.

```
String strSqlUpdate = "UPDATE Customers SET Contact = " + contact_num
              + ",Email = '" + email_add + "'" 
              + ",Address = '" + mail_add + "'" 
              + ",SurveyStatus = '" + radio_group + "'"
              + ",Subscription = '" + receive_info + "' " 
              + "WHERE membership_ID = '" + member_ID + "'";
```

Comment: what do you mean by spaces,sorry

Comment: Select * from TableWhereColumn1=1. This query wont execute since it has no spaces in between the keywords and table name and column name. The string that you are using in your code to construct the sql would produce a sql like how I have mentioned in my answer. If you read the sql you will notice the sql has no spaces between words near the where clause. So, you would have to take care of that in your String in your code.

Comment: The equals operator has to be inside the double quotes. Only then it will be a part of the string

Comment: Edited my answer. Check now.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20331064/insert-record-in-database-dont-work-using-if-else-and-preparedstatement

Answer (score 1):

I get no syntax errors when I declare and Initialize all of the variables. You have to make sure they're all initialized, within the scope of the `strSqlUpdate`

```
String contact_num = "";
String email_add = "";
String mail_add = "";
String radio_group = "";
String receive_info = "";
String member_ID = "";
String strSqlUpdate = " UPDATE Customers SET (Contact)" + contact_num + "," + "Email"
            + email_add + "," + "Address" + "," + mail_add + "," + "SurveyStatus" + "," + radio_group
            + "," + "Subscription" + receive_info + "WHERE MembershipID =" + member_ID;
```

Also considering you're talking about SQL syntax, adding on to what others have said, I'd advise you should use a `PreparedStatement` to avoid SQL injection.

```
PreparedStatement pst = conn.prepareStatement(
                     "UPDATE Customers SET (Contact) ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ? WHERE ? = ?");
pst.setString(1, contact_num);
pst.setString(2, email_add);
... and so on
```

An error in your current SQL syntax is this

```
"Subscription" + receive_info + "WHERE MembershipID
```

Translated as

```
"...Subscrptionreceive_infoWHERE MembershipID..."
```

You need to add spaces wherever you don't have commas

Comment: Hi,
Previously, I did for INSERT Statement, 
it working well.
BUT when I change into update
there's syntax error..

Comment: See the bottom of my answer

Comment: You're still missing the space in front of the WHERE

Comment: Also, you're not even using your single quotes consistently. Though you may even need them.