# Insert record in database don't work, using if else and preparedStatement

Tags: netbeans

I want to check if my record is exist in database
meaning,
if the record is not in database,
it will execute this query and update it in database.
However,
when I run the code,
there isn't any errors,
BUT! it just didn't inserted in.
I have tried null && .equals("")

```
 if (member_ID == null)
 {
 PreparedStatement pstmtInsert = conn.prepareStatement(
"INSERT INTO Customers (MembershipID, Contact, Email, Address, SurveyStatus, Subscription) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");

    pstmtInsert.setString(1,member_ID);
          pstmtInsert.setString(2,contact_num);
          pstmtInsert.setString(3,email_add);
          pstmtInsert.setString(4,mail_add);
          pstmtInsert.setString(5,radio_group);
          pstmtInsert.setString(6,receive_info);         
          pstmtInsert.executeUpdate();
           pstmtInsert.close();
 }
```

Comment: Try printing the value of member_id before the if statement.

Comment: my insert statement work out fine

Comment: Are you sure its going inside the if block ?

Comment: if your else is working, it means it never entered your IF which means your insert statement never got executed

Comment: Are all the columns in your db defined as Strings? no integers?

Comment: I declare as string in my java class